# array_unique ХАЛТУРИТ

Tags: php

Доброго времени всем друзья! вот такой код

```
$file = file_get_contents("alm.txt");//Обращаюсь к текстовому документу при помощи функции file_get_contents();
preg_match_all("/([^,]+)/i", 
     $file,$matches);//Читаю в нём всё кроме запятой и записываю каждый емэйл в отдельную ячейку массива $matches
$arr = $matches;
$arr = array_unique($arr);//выбираю лишь уникальне значения ячеек массива
print_r($arr);  //проверяю ОНИ ВСЁ РАВНО ПОВТОРЯЮТСЯ
```

В чём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = file_get_contents("alm.txt");//Обращаюсь к текстовому документу при помощи функции file_get_contents();
preg_match_all("/([^,]+)/i", 
     $file,$matches);//Читаю в нём всё кроме запятой и записываю каждый емэйл в отдельную ячейку массива $matches
$arr = $matches;
$arr = array_unique($arr[0]);//Изменил эту строчку вот так
var_dump($arr); //ТА ДААА )))
всё заработало! правда я так и не понял что к чему))))
```

Comment: ололо, вы хоть отличаете preg_match_all от preg_match? :D

Comment: нет я новичек в этом деле)) подскажите

Comment: сделайте var_dump($arr) в обоих случаях и поймете разницу :-) Вкратце - preg_match затрагивает одну (входящую в рег. выражение) строку, а preg_match_all - все. По этому и массивы разные.